Movie about a medical student who becomes rich on gold mining in the 19th century
The movie was color and is set some time in 19th century during the gold rush.
A medical student leaves university and to search for a gold mine. He suffers very much and finally finds a mine but it takes 10 years to make money even while he knows he is standing on gold.
His family supports him as long as they can. A shopkeeper who gave the medical student trousers is rewarded by the student after he becomes rich. He becomes the richest man of his age, married to a young lady who met him during a sea voyage. In opposition to tax raises by the government he closes the gold mine. He lives on an island and is killed. He enjoyed his money for a few years.

This shares a similar premise with Eureka (1983) which, although I don't recall a medical student, does involve the main character finding a gold mine, getting fabulously rich, and living the last of their days on a Caribbean island. 
EDIT
After further digging, I think the film is based on the life (and death) of Harry Oakes.
From the wiki page:

Sir Harry Oakes, 1st Baronet (December 23, 1874 Sangerville, Maine –
  July 7, 1943 Nassau, Bahamas) was an American-born British Canadian
  gold mine owner, entrepreneur, investor and philanthropist. He earned his fortune in Canada and moved to the Bahamas in the 1930s for
  tax purposes. He was murdered in 1943 under notorious circumstances
  in the Bahamas.

Two more films were made on the subject:

Any Human Heart (2010) a BBC television movie
Passion and Paradise (1989) a Canadian TV movie


Upon reflection, I was way off :)

I saw Eureka. The story is the same but Eureka is about Jack McCann's last years of life while the movie I remember was about the days he was looking hard over gold.

I dug a little deeper. Not sure if I've struck gold though...
